# How can create Python iplot graph, colors changes with value?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

Here you are part of my data.

[image]

I count my data

```
count_interests = interests.count()
```

then made a graph

```
count_interests.iplot(kind = 'bar', xTitle='Interests', yTitle='Number of Person', colors='Red')
```

[image]

I tried many times to find a function change columns color with values so bigger and smaller columns looks different colors.

I know there is  `colorscale` and `color` functions and I tried many times I couldn't find. Does anyone know any function?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function which returns a color for each value and then pass the colors for each bar in a `list`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly

def color(val, median, std):
    if val > median + std:
            return 'darkgreen'
    if val < median - std:
            return 'darkred'
    return 'orange'

df = pd.DataFrame({'cinema': [1, 2, 5, 3, 3, None],
                   'theatre': [3, 0, 8, 4, 0, 4],
                   'wine': [3, 2, 5, None, 1, None],
                   'beer': [4, 8, 2, None, None, None]})

med = df.count().median()
std = df.count().std()

colors = [color(i, med, std) for i in df.count()]

fig = plotly.graph_objs.Bar(x=df.columns,
                            y=df.count(),
                            marker=dict(color=colors))

plotly.offline.plot([fig])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bars could be also colored either by `pd.pivot_table()` the rows to columns or by creating a separate list of traces for bars. Here, each column was aggregated by taking a `sum()` as an example. Code below:

```
# Import libraries
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pyo


# Create dataframe
INT_M_PUB = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
INT_M_CINEMA = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
INT_M_THEATRE = [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]
INT_M_GYM = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
INT_M_ENTERTAIN = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
INT_M_EATOUT = [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]
INT_M_WINE = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]


interests = pd.DataFrame({'INT_M_PUB':INT_M_PUB, 'INT_M_CINEMA':INT_M_CINEMA, 'INT_M_THEATRE':INT_M_THEATRE,
                   'INT_M_GYM':INT_M_GYM, 'INT_M_ENTERTAIN':INT_M_ENTERTAIN, 'INT_M_EATOUT':INT_M_EATOUT,
                   'INT_M_WINE':INT_M_WINE
                  })
interests.head(2)


dfm = interests.sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'interests', 0:'value'})
dfm

# Re-creating the plot similar to that in question (note: y-axis scales are different)
df = dfm.copy()
col_list = df.columns

df.iplot(kind = 'bar', x='interests', y='value', xTitle='Interests', yTitle='Number of Person', title='These bars need to be colored', color='red')
```

[image]

```
# Color plots by creating traces
# Initialize empty list named data to collect traces for each bar
data = []
for col_name in col_list:
    trace = go.Bar(
        x=[col_name],
        y=df[col_name],
        name=col_name
    )
    data.append(trace)

data = data
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='group',
    title='Interests',
    xaxis=dict(title='Interests'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Number of Person')
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.iplot(fig, filename='grouped-bar')
```

[image]

```
# Creating plot by pivoting the table
df = pd.pivot_table(dfm, values='value', columns='interests')
df.iplot(kind = 'bar',xTitle='Interests', yTitle='Number of Person')
```

[image]